# Correct transmission VIEW by condition (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP and CodeIgniter.I Can not fully understand how to properly transmit a VIEW by some condition. I think this examples not correct, and it can be much, much beautifful and PRO than mine. Tell me how it would be correct?

*My version 1*

**CONTROLLER:**

```
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $data["account"]=$this->ion_auth->logged_in()?true:false;
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('leftFrame', $data);
        $this->load->view('rightFrame');
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="leftFrame">
    <?php 
        if($account == true){
            echo '
                <div class="account">
                    <img src="/images/pic.png">
                </div>
            ';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

*My version 2*

**CONTROLLER:**

```
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()){
            $data["account"] = '<div class="account">
                                    <img src="/images/pic.png">
                                </div>';
        }
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('leftFrame', $data);
        $this->load->view('rightFrame');
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="leftFrame">
    <?php 
        echo $account;
    ?>
</div>
```

*My version 3*

**CONTROLLER:**

```
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        if($this->ion_auth->logged_in()){
            $data["account"] = $this->load->view('account');
        }
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('leftFrame', $data);
        $this->load->view('rightFrame');
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

**VIEW (account.php):**

```
<div class="account">
    <img src="/images/pic.png">
</div>
```

**VIEW (leftFrame.php):**

```
<div class="leftFrame">
    <?php 
        echo $account;
    ?>
</div>
```

**CORRECT ?:**

1? 2? 3? other?

Comment: I would suggest codereview.stackexchange.com for that kind of question.

Comment: 1 mistake, in 2nd option you'll have `<div class="leftFrame">` twice.
1st method is correct and you can use `$data["account"]=$this->ion_auth->logged_in()?true:false`

Comment: Matiit thank you for useful information. I'll try this new platform in a next time.

Comment: Karan, oh sorry, you are right, this is typo mistake, i'll fix it, and yes ternary operator looks prety well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup>** option looks correct, you are passing all values in variable and manipulate HMTL in view..

**2<sup>nd</sup>** you are passing HTML code in variable, syntax correct but view is best place to  manipulate HMTL.

**3<sup>rd</sup>** option looks incorrect because you are trying to parsing view in controller

```
$data["account"] = $this->load->view('account'); //incorrect
```

Right syntax

```
$data["account"] = $this->load->view('account', $data, true);
```

And again passing value in view..

I would recommend,  You should create layout and use sub-view as element, you can get CI layout library [**layout library**](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/layout-library)